# Embedding of modules of finite length

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, cohen-macaulay, artinian

Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $n$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated Artinian $R$-module. One can choose an $R$-sequence $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that there exists a short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow (R/(x_1,...,x_n))^k\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow0.$

My approach was using induction on $l(M)$. I wonder if one can prove this by Matlis duality or other methods.

Comment: @user26857 There is if $M=R/\mathfrak{m}$, since such an $R$ has depth $0$, so $\mathfrak{m}$ is an associated prime of $R$ in that situation. More concerning is the case when $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is Artinian and $M=E_R(k)$. In that case there is an injection $M \to R^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$ if and only if $R$ is Gorenstein.